# Cannot access Plesk http from my ISP

Tags: unix, https, plesk

I've been accessing Plesk Admin for a while at http://yourarthere.net:8443 but since I moved to a new home and ISP (Comcast) I am unable to get to the page using a browser or UNIX wget.

```
# wget http://yourarthere.net:8443 
--2011-08-22 21:13:06--  http://yourarthere.net:8443/
Resolving yourarthere.net (yourarthere.net)... <IP>
Connecting to yourarthere.net (yourarthere.net)|<IP>|:8443...
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ^C <canceled>
```

I can however access the page using my phone or another ISP.

The strange thing is that I can access the page from my home *if* I use a secure connection. I've been told that Plesk should forward to https automatically from http anyway but it isn't for some reason from my ISP (Comcast).

In addition, a second, possibly related issue, is that I am receiving a message that there is a problem with my security certificate. But again, it only happens when I connect from my ISP.

```
# wget https://yourarthere.net:8443/
--2011-08-23 14:02:40--  https://yourarthere.net:8443/
Resolving yourarthere.net (yourarthere.net)... 69.64.52.141
Connecting to yourarthere.net (yourarthere.net)|69.64.52.141|:8443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify yourarthere.net’s certificate, issued by “/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287”:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
To connect to yourarthere.net insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
```

Here is the result from a colleague's attempt from a different ISP:

```
# wget http://yourarthere.net:8443
--2011-08-23 14:41:53--  http://yourarthere.net:8443/
Resolving yourarthere.net... 69.64.52.141
Connecting to yourarthere.net|69.64.52.141|:8443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://yourarthere.net:8443/ [following]
--2011-08-23 14:41:53--  https://yourarthere.net:8443/
Connecting to yourarthere.net|69.64.52.141|:8443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.2'
```

Comment: do u have a firewall ? we recently got into the same situation and at the end it was from our smoothwall firewall

Comment: Only the linksys router default firewall which block incoming requests... One thing that is weird about my connection at my home is that I had to clone the MAC address of my computer with my wireless router in order to use more than one computer here. http://owenmundy.com/blog/2011/08/internet-service-just-got-creepy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a misconfigured SSL on the server which caused an error in the forwarding process. Problem fixed now.